# Images within content of page but not separate fields

Tags: media, 7

I would like to create a basic page within Drupal 7 that would consist of some images mixed with HTML. I would use CSS to position the images within the HTML content, sort of like a magazine or newspaper article.

I would like for the end user to be able to edit/replace these images along with the HTML yet the image field did not seem to give me flexibility to place the image within the HTML content.

I could upload the images via FTP directly to the `../sites/default/files` directory and manually reference the images ...

```
<img src="../sites/default/files/image-name.png" />
```

but that would not allow the end users to manage the images from with Drupal, plus I would need to give them FTP access to the filesystem which I would like to avoid.

Any suggestions on how to work around this?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I would like to find a solution where the end user can upload content (i.e. images) themselves.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the following modules:

- [WYSIWYG](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg)
- [CKEditor module](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) with [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) library
- [IMCE module](http://drupal.org/project/imce):

Lot of setup and config, but once its there, its there so to speak.

Comment: Just to add, you don't need both WYSIWYG and CKEditor drupal modules, only one of them should suffice. I prefer WYSIWYG module.

Comment: FYI:  WYSIWYG module supports the following editors:  CKEditor, FCKeditor, jWysiwyg, markItUp, NicEdit, openWYSIWYG, TinyMCE, Whizzywig, WYMeditor, YUI editor

Comment: I installed WYSIWYG. Then tried installing the latest CKEditor (v4). WYSIWYG did not recognize it. I then installed the latest 3.x version of CKEditor and it worked fine.

Comment: This solution provides no way for the user to upload an image.

Comment: Care to elaborate webform? Id be suprised if you find an alternative.