# get embeded images from text into field

Tags: entities, views, nodes

Objective:
Extract image (ideally into a new field) from an existing text field in a custom entity with views handler (civicrm view or civicrm_entity).

Scenario:
HTML fields often has an image or multiple images embedded. In this case, the content is sourced from a civicrm external entity using civicrm views (could also be done using civicrm_entity module).  Views provides text field filters and can strip html tags, but I **only** want to extract one or more images from the html.  This can then be displayed as a seperate field in views (either as a new / generated field) or reusing the description field and stripping out everything else.

Notes:
This seems easy, but the field formatter needs to work with remote urls.  I tried the [Image Resize Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_resize_filter) which works on remote urls, but i need to also strip the rest of the text.  This does not actually create a new field, and is pretty ugly, but can work.

Modules considered / reviews:
https://www.drupal.org/project/image_link_formatter - not a node, only avail as view
https://www.drupal.org/project/image_importer - like idea of importing as "Drupal" image but no easy way to link embeded image to file system

Discusssions:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1045712
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/138961/get-images-from-textfield-and-save-them-in-filefield
[Images within content of page but not separate fields](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53848/images-within-content-of-page-but-not-separate-fields)